# JS Prototypal Inheritance: childs use the same parent properties?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

Let's say I have Player object:

```
var player = function(name) {
    this.handlers = {};
}

player.prototype.on = function(event, callback) {
    if (!this.handlers[event]) {
        this.handlers[event] = [];
    }
    this.handlers[event].push(callback);
}
```

It works great, I can create players and each will have its own set of handlers. Now suppose I need to inherit from `player`:

```
var testPlayer = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

testPlayer.prototype = new player();
```

Now when I create `testPlayer`'s, each of them share the same `handlers` property:

```
var adam = new testPlayer('Adam');
adam.on('test', function(){});

var eve = new testPlayer('Eve');
// eve.handlers == {'test':<function>}
```

What am I missing here? I understand than every `testPlayer`'s prototype is the same `new player` object I create when describing child class. But is there some way for all testPlayers to have their own set of handlers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sure looks strange for those used to classical inheritance, but it's how prototypal inheritance works. To have a separate handlers object per instance, you need to specify one on the child constructor. That will shadow the prototype's property with the same name:

```
var testPlayer = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.handlers = {};
};

testPlayer.prototype = new player();
```

Another solution would be to create this shadowing property on-demand, from your `on` method:

```
player.prototype.on = function(event, callback) {
    // Check for a handlers property on the instance
    if(!this.hasOwnProperty('handlers') {
        this.handlers = {};
    }
    if (!this.handlers[event]) {
        this.handlers[event] = [];
    }
    this.handlers[event].push(callback);
}
```

---

**Interesting fact**

This is only a problem if you're modifying properties of an object (or array) on the prototype. If you try to assign to properties that live on the prototype, a local shadowing property will be created automatically (you can't assign to prototype properties from instances).

Comment: +1 for the "another solution", this looks like the most usable.

Comment: I agree, that's a totally valid programming paradigm. The annoying part is that you have to add such a check in every method that uses `handlers`.

Comment: You could have a single `init` method called from the constructor, and do it from there. Note that this is only a problem if you're modifying properties of an object (or array) on the prototype. If you try to assign to properties that live on the prototype, a local shadowing property will be created automatically (you can't assign to prototype properties from instances).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `handlers` is a property that was added in the *constructor*, so when you do

```
testPlayer.prototype = new player();
```

you're adding every property of a brand new `player` object to `testPlayer.prototype`, and that *includes* `handlers`.

So, there's a `handlers` property in every `testPlayer` object, and when you add a property to `handlers` you're adding the property to the object *in the prototype*, and not of the `testPlayer` object.

In short, when calling the `on` method you're adding a property to `testPlayer.prototype.handlers`, not `adam.handlers` or `eve.handlers`.

To be safe, define:

```
var testPlayer = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.handlers = {};
};
```